# Return masked array as simple array with masked values as None

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

I need to mask an array `a` by a condition fulfilled by another array `b`.

For example values in `a` should only be preserved if the values in the same position of `b` equal 0, otherwise return as `None`. For example:

```
a = np.array([2, 2, 4, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2])
```

is masked by

```
b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0])
```

to return

```
c: [2, 2, 4, None, 4, None, 3, None, 1, 2]
```

I have tried

```
to_change = np.ma.masked_where(travel_time!=0, new_subareas)
```

but this returns:

```
masked_array(data=[2, 2, 4, --, 4, --, 3, --, 1, 2],
             mask=[False, False, False,  True, False,  True, 
                   False,  True, False, False],
                   fill_value=999999)
```

But I can't find anything that will just return something like the example given for `c`.

I need something done entirely in `numpy` and without for-loops or if statements, for speed as this will be for very large arrays. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need a new array or would an in-place solution modifying `a` suffice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`masked_array`s have a little more overhead, in that operations on these implicitly ignore masked values (and work on everything else instead).

If you are not looking for that kind of functionality, you can just use `np.where`, but you risk converting your array to an `object`.

```
np.where(b == 0, a, None)
array([2, 2, 4, None, 4, None, 3, None, 1, 2], dtype=object)
```

I'd recommend substitution with `NaN` instead?

```
np.where(b == 0, a, np.nan)
array([ 2.,  2.,  4., nan,  4., nan,  3., nan,  1.,  2.])
```

Preserves the numeric type.

Comment: Perfect and much simpler, especially with np.nan as I am trying to preserve the numeric type, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an in-place solution, you can convert to `a` to `float` and then use `np.where`.

Float conversion is required here as `np.nan` is a `float`.

```
a = np.array([2, 2, 4, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2])
b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0])

a = a.astype(float)
a[np.where(b!=0)] = np.nan

# array([  2.,   2.,   4.,  nan,   4.,  nan,   3.,  nan,   1.,   2.])
```